# Possible to create new playlist on Spotify through terminal?

Tags: terminal, spotify, osascript

Found out that I am able to control Spotify through terminal from here
http://www.instructables.com/id/RFID-Controls-for-Spotify-on-OSX-using-hacked-Mir/?ALLSTEPS

for example skipping to the next song, you would type this in the terminal:
osascript -e 'tell application "Spotify" to next track'

Just wanted to know if there was a way to create a new playlist on Spotify through the terminal .

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

No, creating playlists it's not possible using the desktop application's API.

Some useful resources:

- The API reference can be found at `/Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Resources/Spotify.sdef`
- A shorter guide can be found at https://developer.spotify.com/applescript-api/